# Kml Toolbox Matlab Contour Animation

Tags: matlab, animation, kml

I am trying to set up an animation with matlab kml toolbox.
I can set it up such that a wind turbine model rotates as the time passes. 
my problem is I am trying to update the contour plots that are also embedded to google earth to be updated with time. my code looks as in;

```
time=0:0.05:3;
dT=time(2)-time(1);
s = kml('turbinanim');
f = s.createFolder(['FreqSHeight']);
Lptemp=rand(size(Long))*100;
modelbl=s.model(longitude(i,1),latitude(i,1),altitude(i,1),yaw(i,1),tilt(i,1),roll(i,1),''model'',''C:\Users\ebarlas\Desktop\ge_tu\files\Blades0.dae')
anim = s.newAnimation('3TurbineMat');
for i=2:length(time)
anim.updateOrientation(modelbl,dT,yaw(i),tilt(i),roll(1))'])
anim.flyToLookAt(dT,   -8.813385+i*3e-5,   41.751632+i*1e-4, 450,'relativeToGround',10,80)
%%     f.contourf(Long,Latti,Lptemp,'transparency',0.6,'numberOfLevels', [0:20:100]);
end
```

any idea how to make f.contourf to be time dependent

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out this is how the code looks like for time dependent animation with contour plots on google earth.

```
time=0:0.05:3;
dT=time(2)-time(1);
s = kml('turbinanim');
modelbl=s.model(longitude(i,1),latitude(i,1),altitude(i,1),yaw(i,1),tilt(i,1),roll(i,1),''model'',''C:\Users\ebarlas\Desktop\ge_tu\files\Blades0.dae')
anim = s.newAnimation('3TurbineMat');
for i=2:length(time)
    Lptemp=rand(size(Long))*100;
    anim.updateOrientation(modelbl,dT,yaw(i),tilt(i),roll(1))'])
    anim.flyToLookAt(dT,   -8.813385+i*3e-5,   41.751632+i*1e-4, 450,'relativeToGround',10,80)
    tbegin=[num2str(1900+i*4),'-01-28T02:02:10Z'];
    tend=[num2str(1900+(i+1)*4),'-01-28T02:02:10Z'];
    f = s.createFolder(['FreqSHeight',num2str(i)]);
    f.contourf(Long,Latti,Lptemp,'transparency',0.6,'numberOfLevels',[0:20:100],'timeSpanBegin',tbegin,'timeSpanEnd',tend);
end
s.run;
```